# How do I repeat Select on a list as the elements of said list are manipulated?

Tags: list-manipulation

Using some list manipulation I am able to produce a list of eigenvalues `eigenim` of the form `{d,#[[2]]}`, where `d` is some parameter, and `#[[2]]` is the imaginary part of each eigenvalue. I then use `SelectFirst` to extract the first `{d,#[[2]]}` for which `#[[2]]` is nonzero.

```
dmax=0.2;
s[d_?NumericQ] := SolveValues[r^3 - 10 r^2 + (25 + 100d^2) r - 4 == 0, r, Reals]
eigenfunc[{d_,r_}] := {d, (0.5 - 0.2 r + # Sqrt[0.01 r^2 - d^2])} & /@ {1, -1};

rvalues = 
  Join @@ (Transpose /@ 
     Table[{Array[d &, Length[s[d]]], s[d]}, {d, 0, dmax, 0.0001}]);

eigenvalues = Catenate[eigenfunc /@ rvalues];
eigenim = MapAt[Im, eigenvalues, {All, 2}];
SelectFirst[eigenim, 0.0 < #[[2]] &]
```

This generates
{0.0172, 0.00150665}.
I wish to repeat this process for different values of a parameter `f`, such that `f=dmax` and our cubic becomes:

```
r^3 - 10 r^2 + (25 + 100d^2) r - 100f^2 == 0
```

but instead of our output being some `{d,#[[2]]}`, I wish to extract the `d` from the first nonzero `#[[2]]`, along with the `f`. This gives a single `{d,f}` for each value of `f`, such that the domain of `f` is `[0,2]` with some step size `df=0.01`.

Comment: You can use `rvalues = Catenate @ Table[Thread @ {d, s[d]}, {d, 0, dmax, 0.0001}]` which calls the `s` one time and is simpler.

Comment: I've now got some function ```t[f]``` such that 
```eigenfunc[{d_, r_}] := {d, (0.5 - 0.2 r + # Sqrt[0.01 r^2 - d^2])} & /@ {1, -1};
t[f_] := SelectFirst[MapAt[Im, Catenate[eigenfunc /@Catenate@Table[Thread@{d, SolveValues[r^3 - 10 r^2 + (25 + 100*d^{2}) r - 100 f^2 == 0, r, Reals]}, {d, 0, f, 0.0001}]], {All, 2}], 0.0 < #[[2]] &];``` If I run ```Evaluate[{t[f]} /. (t[#] & /@ Range[0.01, 2, 0.01])]```, the process will seemingly take hours or even days. Is there a better way to do this/ how can I end up with ```{d, f}```-- currently my ```t[f]``` gives some list of the form ```{d, #[[2]]}```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the greatest advantages of Mathematica is its symbolic engine. Many functions support symbolic expression which can be cached for further use. Here is how I would tackle such problems:

```
Block[{temp1, temp2, temp3, temp4, f, r, d},

 temp1 = 
  SolveValues[r^3 - 10 r^2 + (25 + 100 d^2) r - 100 f^2 == 0, r, Reals];

 temp2 = 
  Catenate@
   Table[Im[(0.5 - 0.2 r + # Sqrt[0.01 r^2 - d^2])] & /@ {1, -1}, {r, temp1}];
 
 temp3 = temp2 /. {f -> .2};

Do[temp4 = SelectFirst[temp3, GreaterThan[0], {}];
   If[temp4 =!= {}, Return@{d, temp4}]
   
   , {d, 0, .2, .0001}]
  
  ]
```

which output `{0.0172, 0.0015066530736155246}` 60 times faster (on my computer it took around `0.2` seconds - The original solution took around `14` seconds) while using 19 times lower memory at peak.

First, we solve the expression symbolically, then apply transformations and `Im` to it. Then in the `Do` loop, we iterate over each `d` (instead of populating for all possible values), if we find the solution, it returns the result.

I should also point out the slight differences in the results:

```
(* Original Output: *)
{0.0172`, 0.0015066530736155606`}

(* Proposed Output: *)
{0.0172`, 0.0015066530736155246`}
```

Remember there is always room for improvement and I'm sure somebody in this forum can substantially improve this code.